# Counting number of inversions

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorica

Is there an inbuilt method to find the number of inversions in a set of numbers? I found `Inversions` in `Combinatorica` but when I tried to use it as `Inversions[{1,4,2,5,2,3,2}]` it doesn't return a number as a result. How are you supposed to use the function?

Comment: That's because `{1,4,2,5,2,3,2}` is not a permutation.  A permutation of length `n` contains precisely the elements `Range[n]` in some order.

Comment: Also, to use a function in `Combinatorica` you must first load the package with Needs["Combinatorica`"]

Comment: @Szabolcs Is there any way to make it work for a general set of elements?

Comment: @user2612743 You'll have to roll your own.  The simplest approach is brute forcing it as george2079 did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 myinversions[list_] := 
     Select[ Subsets[Range[Length[list]], {2}] , 
        list[[#[[1]]]] > list[[#[[2]]]] & ] // Length
```

Verify the same result as builtin `Inversions` for a permutation

```
 Needs["Combinatorica`"]
 And @@ (Inversions[#] == myinversions[#] & /@ Permutations[Range[5]])
```

> True

```
 myinversions[{1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2}]
```

> 8

Answer (score 5):

The presently Accepted solution is quite slow, at least on long lists.  We can improve performance of this brute-force algorithm by orders of magnitude using numeric vector operations.  Consider:

```
f1[a_] /; VectorQ[a, IntegerQ] :=
  Sum[Tr @ Clip[a[[i]] ~Subtract~ Drop[a, i], {0, 1}], {i, Length@a}]

f1[a_List] := f1 @ Ordering @ a
```

Compared to `myinversions` on numeric data:

```
big = RandomInteger[5000, 2000];
r1 = myinversions[big]; // Timing // First
r2 = f1[big]; // Timing // First
r1 === r2
```

> ```
> 2.589
> 0.01684
> True
> ```

The second definition lets the function operate on arbitrary expressions by converting with `Ordering`:

```
RandomChoice[DictionaryLookup[], 6]
% // f1
```

> ```
> {"illustrate", "reconstruct", "fine", "furry", "Ivorian", "dinghy"}
> 10
> ```

I suspect there is a yet faster way using a sort-based algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Still 4X slower than @Mr.W' method, but much faster than ones in the original post is

```
 invF5 = With[{ss = Subtract @@ Transpose[Subsets[#, {2}]]}, Total@UnitStep[ss]] &
```

---

```
invF = Total@(1 - UnitStep[Order @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]]) &
```

or

```
invF2 = Count[Subsets[#, {2}], _?(Greater @@ # &)] &;
```

or, variations on george2079's approach

```
invF3 = Length@Select[Subsets[#, {2}], Greater @@ # &] &;
invF4 = Length@Select[Subsets[#, {2}], Composition[Not, OrderedQ]] &;

l1 = RandomSample[Range[5]];
{l1, invF[l1], invF2[l1], invF3[l1], invF4[l1]}
(* {{5,4,1,3,2}, 8, 8, 8, 8} *)
```

Using the test in @george2079's answer:

```
And @@ Equal @@@ ({invF[#], invF2[#], invF3[#], invF4[#], myinversions[#]} & /@ 
   Permutations[Range[5]]) 
(* True *)
```